# HttpWebRequest GET returns 'No Content' after successful POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net

I'm working on an app that makes a POST to a REST API that returns a URI in its response. I then am to make a GET request to that URI and it is supposed to return HTML content in the response body. However, the GET request returns 'No Content' in its HTTP Status Code.

What's strange is, I have a small console app I built for testing purposes that if I plug the URI into it (allows me to test the GET without making the POST), the status good is 200 - OK and I receive the HTML content in the body. So it seems it is related to something I'm doing in my POST request. Here is my code (sensitive info has been redacted):

```
private PersonReportResults POSTReportRequest(PersonReportRequest reportRequest)
{
    var personReportResults = new PersonReportResults();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/personReport/reportResults");

    var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    var serializedXml = Serialize(reportRequest);
    xDoc.LoadXml(serializedXml);

    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xDoc.OuterXml);
    request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXUserId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXPassword"]);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(GetClientCertificate());

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (responseStream.CanRead && count > 0);
                ms.Position = 0;

                // now attempt to desrialize from the memory stream
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonReportResults));
                personReportResults = ((PersonReportResults)serializer.Deserialize(ms));
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        request.Abort();
    }
    return personReportResults;
}

/// <summary>
/// Makes a HTTP GET request for the report HTML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
/// <returns>string</returns>
private static string GETResults(string uri)
{
    var responseHTML = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri + "?reportType=html");

    //request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXUserId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXPassword"]);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(GetClientCertificate());

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            var count = 0;
                            do
                            {
                                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                                ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                            } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
                            ms.Position = 0;

                            var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                            responseHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        //var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                        //responseHTML = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            request.Abort();
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            response.Close();

            var tryCount = 1;
            while (tryCount < 5)
            {
                using (var retryResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (retryResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (var stream = retryResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            if (stream != null)
                            {
                                var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                                responseHTML = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                tryCount++;
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
    return responseHTML;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use something like Fiddler to inspect the HTTP requests of both the console app and the actual code?

Comment: If you're getting a 204 on the GET call that follows the POST, 204 is still considered successful -- it may be just that the data isn't completely written yet. Try putting in a sleep after the initial POST and before the GET. I also recommend that you try debugging this with something like Fiddler or Runscope (https://www.runscope.com). With Runscope you don't have to install anything -- simply modify the URL so that it will proxy through Runscope and you can view the live traffic stream (full request and response data). Docs here: https://www.runscope.com/docs/debugging